# convertCoordinate toPointToView returning bad results with tilted maps

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a UIView overlayed on a map, and I'm drawing some graphics in screen space between two of the coordinates using

```
- (CGPoint)convertCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate toPointToView:(UIView *)view
```

The problem is that when the map is very zoomed in and tilted (3D-like), the pixel position of the coordinate that is way off-screen stops being consistent. Sometimes the function returns NaN, sometimes it returns the right number and others it jumps to the other side of the screen.

Not sure how can I explain it better. Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0):

During research have find a many solution. Any solution might be work for you.

Solution:1

```
int x =  (int) ((MAP_WIDTH/360.0) * (180 + lon));
int y =  (int) ((MAP_HEIGHT/180.0) * (90 - lat));
```

Solution:2

```
func addLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    {
        // max MKMapPoint values
        let maxY = Double(267995781)
        let maxX = Double(268435456)

        let mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate)

        let normalizatePointX = CGFloat(mapPoint.x / maxX)
        let normalizatePointY = CGFloat(mapPoint.y / maxY)
        print(normalizatePointX)
        print(normalizatePointX)
    }
```

Solutuin:3

```
x = (total width of image in px) * (180 + latitude) / 360
y = (total height of image in px) * (90 - longitude) / 180
```

note: when using negative longitude of latitude make sure to add or subtract the negative number i.e. +(-92) or -(-35) which would actually be -92 and +35